# Using Amazon S3 in Scala Error [RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/util/BlockingThreadPoolExecutorService]

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, noclassdeffounderror

I am new to big data development and S3 in particular. I have a Scala project (PlayFrameWork) which I've been using HDFS for so far. Now I am trying to switch to S3. I have a very simple code which reads a file from S3:

```
     val sparkSession: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder
        .master("local[*]")
        .appName("SparkSessionZipsExample")
        .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///C:/projects/scala101")
        .getOrCreate()

         val sonnets: String = sparkSession.sparkContext
                                      .wholeTextFiles("s3a://<awsAccessKey>:<awsASecretccessKey>@logs/Results.json")
                                      .take(1)(0)._2
         println(sonnets)
```

In my build.sbt I have added some commanded dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "2.7.3" % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-s3" % "1.11.307"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-aws" % "3.0.1"
```

But yet I am getting the following error:

```
[error] application - 

! @77fbmca9f - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/util/BlockingThreadPoolExecutorService]]
    at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:255)
    at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:180)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer$$anonfun$3.applyOrElse(AkkaHttpServer.scala:310)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer$$anonfun$3.applyOrElse(AkkaHttpServer.scala:308)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:346)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:345)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run$$$capture(Promise.scala:36)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/util/BlockingThreadPoolExecutorService
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anon$2.apply(Action.scala:424)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Action.scala:96)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Action.scala:89)
    at play.api.libs.streams.StrictAccumulator$$anonfun$mapFuture$2$$anonfun$1.apply(Accumulator.scala:174)
    at play.api.libs.streams.StrictAccumulator$$anonfun$mapFuture$2$$anonfun$1.apply(Accumulator.scala:174)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at play.api.libs.streams.StrictAccumulator$$anonfun$mapFuture$2.apply(Accumulator.scala:174)
    at play.api.libs.streams.StrictAccumulator$$anonfun$mapFuture$2.apply(Accumulator.scala:170)
    at akka.stream.impl.Transform.apply(TraversalBuilder.scala:155)
    at akka.stream.impl.PhasedFusingActorMaterializer.materialize(PhasedFusingActorMaterializer.scala:482)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/util/BlockingThreadPoolExecutorService
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.initialize(S3AFileSystem.java:254)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3288)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:123)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3337)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3305)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:476)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:361)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(FileInputFormat.java:514)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(FileInputFormat.java:483)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$wholeTextFiles$1.apply(SparkContext.scala:877)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.util.BlockingThreadPoolExecutorService
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.initialize(S3AFileSystem.java:254)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3288)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:123)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3337)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3305)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:476)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:361)
```

I appreciate any help.
Thank you,